# bot framework recognizer doesn't override default dialog

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I'm trying to have a custom dialog fire when a user hits certain keywords (like "bathroom"), and according to the Bot Framework tutorial on [recognizing user intent from message content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-recognize-intent-messages?view=azure-bot-service-3.0): `Intent recognizers are global, which means that the recognizer will run for every message received from the user. If a recognizer detects an intent that is bound to a dialog using a triggerAction, it can trigger interruption of the currently active dialog. Allowing and handling interruptions is a flexible design that accounts for what users really do.`  So what I've done is created a recognizer mirroring the format of the one in the tutorial and then have a dialog that triggers off of that recognizer, also mirroring the format of the tutorial.  However, no matter what i type, keyword or otherwise, the bot only initiates the default dialog, which seems to contradict the `global` aspect of the intent recognizer.  I'd like to keep my default dialog in the bot's instantiation, as it is the main interaction that should be had with the bot, so is there any way to resolve this issue with that constraint?

Relevant code snippets bellow:

```
//instantiate the bot with the default dialog
let bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
    (session) =>{
        //default dialog code here
    }
]);

//recognizers
//for nearest bathroom
bot.recognizer(new builder.RegExpRecognizer("NearestBathroom", {en_us: /^(bathroom|restroom|toilet)/i}));

//Dialog for locating a room triggered by the recognizers above
bot.dialog('locationDialog', [
    (session) => {
        //dialog code here
    }
]).triggerAction({ matches: 'NearestBathroom' });
```

Comment: Not 100% sure about this, but are you sure that the execution context is the same as in the examples now that you're using arrow functions? Does anything change if you use es5 function syntax?

Comment: Are you using luis?